# Selecting based on multiple values with the same ID

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
f_id | word
1      foo
1      something
1      bar
2      foo
3      bar
4      else
```

Now, through some input, I get `foo bar` value, I have to explode it, and fetch the `f_id` containing both of these words, not just one of them.

So for this example, for `foo bar` string, I would get `f_id = 1`, for `foo` I'd get 1 and 2, for `bar` I'd get 1 and 3.

How do I make such a query? It has to be as fast as possible, becuase the table has hundreds of millions records, and is executed really often.

---

For just one word, I was doing:

`SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.word = :word`

So it was very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LIKE to find the matching words. Then group by f_id and count and see if you found as many matches as words in the search string.

```
select f_id
from t
where concat(' ', @words, ' ') like concat('% ', word, ' %')
group by f_id
having count(*) = length(@words) - length(replace(@words, ' ') + 1;
```

This relies on the words in the string being separated by *single* blanks and having no leading or trailing blanks. So either ensure this when entering the string or write a stored procedure to convert the string to such format.

This query is not fast. It would be faster to write the query dynamically and get for example:

```
select f_id
from t
where word in ('foo', 'bar')
group by f_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

(provided `word` is indexed of course.)

Comment: Like is way to slow. I have tried your second query, but it returns result if there's `foo foo` match, not only `foo bar`

Comment: You mean the search string is 'foo foo'? That string must not be allowed of course. Or do you mean there are duplicates in the table? Then replace `count(*)` with `count(distinct word)`.

Comment: I mean if there are `1 - foo, 1 - foo` rows I would get 1 as a result, whereas I should get 1 only if there's `1 - foo, 1 - bar`.

Comment: Okay, as mentioned, replace `count(*)` with `count(distinct word)` in the queries then. But why do you have duplicate values in your table at all? No wonder your table is so big :-)

Comment: Huh, you're right, I made a mistake, I don't have duplicates of course, the primary key is on both column so I can't have them ;)

Answer (score 0):

The old query can be joined on itself for 2 conditions.
The query would look like:

```
SELECT t1.f_id FROM 
table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 
ON t1.word = :word1 
 AND t2.word = :word2 
 AND t1.f_id = t1.f_id
GROUP BY t1.f_id
```

To get better performance: add an Index over the `word` column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT f_id FROM (
 SELECT f_id, count(f_id) as count 
 FROM table t 
 WHERE t.word IN (word1,word2)
 group by f_id
) t2
WHERE t2.count = 2
```

i belive it should help you ( i asume every word shown only one time for each f_id)